# What's the north boundary of the KINS Class D? (Or: does a SUA designation take precedence over controlled airspace?)

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, special-use-airspace, class-d-airspace

This is inspired by [the question regarding aerobatics over a surface class D area](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35407/can-aerobatics-be-performed-over-a-controlled-airport).

[KINS (Creech AFB)](http://airnav.com/airport/KINS) sits right outside the south boundary of the Nellis Range Complex (R4806W to be precise).  Considering this, and considering that it has surface Class D around it whenever the tower's open as per the A/FD...does that class D airspace abruptly end where R4806W begins just north of the airbase, or does it continue all the way around, leaving a portion of airspace that's *both* a Class D (sfc) area *and* SUA (i.e. restricted airspace)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the sectional chart, Class D airspace does not extend into the restricted area.

[image: KINS Sectional Chart]

<sup>[SkyVector KINS Sectional Chart](https://skyvector.com/?ll=36.697787265228925,-115.36019897062675&chart=301&zoom=2)</sup>

The restricted airspace starts at the surface to an unlimited altitude.  According the [JO 7400_11A.pdf](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400_11A.pdf), Class D does not enter the restricted area.

[image: JO 7400_11A page 377]

Class E airspace is the same.

[image: JO 7400_11A page 1360]

Comment: The sectional chart does display it that way -- but I'm not sure if that reflects the actual airspace boundaries, is a charting limitation, or if something else is going on (note that the vignette doesn't extend along SUA boundary)

Comment: Vignette?  Are you talking about Class E airspace starting at 700' AGL.  If so, it stops where the restricted area begins leading credence to Class D also stopping where the restricted area begins.

Comment: Ah -- I got the vignette and the dashed line mixed up -- but you'd think they'd draw a dashed line (and/or vignette) parallel to the SUA boundary if the Class D and E airspaces ended at the SUA boundary, no?

Comment: Page 377 of the linked to document contains the information you are looking for.  It is regulatory in nature as it is referenced in §71.61.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after, thanks!