# Considering all US untowered airports, what is the furthest distance that E2 airspace (dashed magneta line) projects from the airport?

Tags: airspace, aeronautical-charts, class-e-airspace

Considering all US untowered airports (50 states), what is the furthest distance that E2 airspace (dashed magneta line) projects from the airport for which it is designated?

Measure from the middle of the airport, or if the airspace is officially defined from a navaid or other feature that lies on the airport, measure from that navaid.

Example of E2 airspace -- KONP-- http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=44.580&lon=-124.058&zoom=10

On this airport, only the inner circle is E2 airspace.  The outer projections are E4 and don't count for this question-- http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=38.894&lon=-119.995&zoom=10

Beware these 3 airspaces, they are special anomalies, they appear to be all E2 but the projections are actually E4 (see related question [Why are KACV and KTLV depicted differently on sectional charts than KSGU, KBIH, and KTPL, even though each is E2 w/ E4 extensions?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64006/why-are-kacv-and-ktlv-depicted-differently-on-sectional-charts-than-ksgu-kbih) ).  To my knowledge these are the only 3 of this kind:

KSGU -- St. George Regional Airport, UT -- http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=37.036&lon=-113.510&zoom=10

KBIH -- Bishop Airport, Bishop CA -- http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=37.373&lon=-118.364&zoom=10

KTPL -- Temple, Draughon-Miller Central Texas Regional Airport, TX -- http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=31.152&lon=-97.408&zoom=10

Except for these three anomalies, you can generally assume that a dashed magenta line surrounding the airport whose approaches it protects, with no inner dashed magenta line, denotes E2 airspace.

Don't be shy about posting the longest answer you've found -- if someone else posts longer no big deal.

Give you best guestimate by measuring on sectional, or check this document for the actual airspace description-- E2 airspaces are listed on pages E-2 through E-141 and have "E2" in the heading, like this:

"ANM OR E2 Newport, OR
Newport Municipal Airport, OR
 (lat. 44°34'49"N., long. 124°03'28"W.)
Newport VORTAC
 (lat. 44°34'31"N., long. 124°03'38"W.)
Within a 4-mile radius of the Newport Municipal Airport, and within 3.5 miles each side of the Newport VORTAC 357° radial extending from the 4-mile radius to 7.9 miles north of
the VORTAC."

In any case of doubt, use the document linked above to definitively determine for which airport the E2 airspace in question has been designated.

State whether measuring in nautical miles or statute miles

The document above uses nautical miles (p. A-2).

Comment: I'm not complaining because lord knows I've asked [some pretty niche questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/826/167) myself, but is there a reason for this question?

Comment: I've been interested in trying to understand airspace design-- why are airports surrounded by such extensive areas of class-E-to-surface airspace-- don't the nearby Class E floors of 1200' AGL or 700' AGL adequately protect the instrument approaches for much of this airspace?  So, an example of an extreme case was desired.  I've marked the question as answered.  Note that such a large block of E2 airspace is quite an impediment to ultralight aviation-- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/which-parts-of-class-e-airspace-can-an-ultralight-part-103-fly-in-without-prio

Comment: At the time the question was asked, I didn't know the answer, but then I went through this document https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_7400.11C.pdf and looked at all the E2 airspace descriptions so I believe the answer given is the correct one.

Comment: A related question could be asked, asking why the E2 airspace at Sheridan is so extensive

Comment: The paragraph beginning "In case of any doubt" should be modified to include a description of this document and a link to it-- the FAA's "Airspace Designations and Reporting Points" document Order 7400.11C ( https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_7400.11C.pdf ).  I thought that I had referenced that document earlier in the question, but I didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best candidate so far--

Sheridan County Airport-- Sheridan, Wyoming-- KSHR
Page E-92 in the "Airspace Designations" document

The E-2 airspace extends 17.6 (nautical) miles southeast of the airport-- and also 16 miles northwest of the airport  -- last amended 5/31/12

http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=44.769&lon=-106.980&zoom=10

Comment: As an aside, the US airport with the most extensive area of E4 airspace in terms of surface area appears to be Casper WY.  This could be the subject of another question/ answer.  http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=42.906&lon=-106.464&zoom=10

Comment: This answer could be modified to reflect that it based on thoroughly going through this document faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_7400.11C.pdf and looking at all the E2 airspace descriptions, so it is probably the correct one.