# How may one notify the FAA of the apparent flaw in the airspace design at KEGE?

Tags: airspace, faa, class-e-airspace

Several questions and answers have addressed the design of the airspace around KEGE.  The situation is perhaps best summarized in this answer -- [Can the Class-E-to-surface airspace near Eagle County Regional airport KEGE be ignored when the tower is open?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64076/can-the-class-e-to-surface-airspace-near-eagle-county-regional-airport-kege-be-i/65402#65402) .  How may one notify the FAA of this apparent flaw in the design of the airspace?  Note that this is not a charting error, but rather an apparent error or omission in the way the airspace has been designated, as described in the "Airspace Designations and Reporting Points" document JO 7400.11C.

Answer (score 3):

From the JO 7400.11C, page (ii)

> 7. Request for Information.  For further information, contact the Airspace Policy Group, Federal Aviation Administration, 800
>      Independence Avenue, SW, Washington, DC  20591; telephone: (202)
>      267-8783.

They will likely connect you with the specific airspace coordinator for the region of interest.