# To what FAA office or personnel should one direct an inquiry about the reasons behind the airspace design at a particular airport?

Tags: airspace, faa, class-e-airspace

The airspace design process is extremely complex.  See for example [this FAA document, Order 7400.2M](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400.2M_Bsc_dtd_2-28-19.pdf).

To what FAA office or personnel should one direct an inquiry about the reasons behind the design of the airspace around one particular airport?

I'm seeking real-world, practical insight as to why the unusual airspace configuration we see at [KACV](http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=40.978&lon=-124.108&zoom=10) and [KTVL](http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=38.894&lon=-119.995&zoom=10) was selected, over the common configuration that we see for example at [KONP](http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=44.580&lon=-124.058&zoom=10) and [KCEC](http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=41.780&lon=-124.237&zoom=10).

I'm specifically seeking information about why the airspace was designed that way, not about how it is being handled now in actual practice by ARTCC etc.

These two airspaces are rather unusual and it's unlikely that a satisfactory answer will be obtained just by perusing the FAA documents giving general guidance on how to design airspace to handle existing/ proposed instrument procedures, etc.

However any kind of actual "paper trail" relating to the design of the airspace at these two particular airports could possibly be helpful, if it were not too "dense" to interpret -- how might that be obtained?

But I'd prefer to speak to an actual person, if he/she had some relevant insight on the design process for the airspace at either of these airports.

Although guidance concerning my specific case is most welcome, also I'm seeking an answer crafted in such a way as to be helpful to anyone seeking  to answer a similar question for any airport in any region of the nation-- how to go about locating an appropriate person or FAA office to direct such a query toward?

Comment: I just looked at a chart and I don't see anything particularly unusual about the airspace around KACV and KTVL.  What is it about that particular configuration that puzzles you?

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/63970/what-is-the-primary-reason-that-the-non-towered-airports-kacv-and-ktlv-have-e4-e

Comment: Compare and  contrast  the 4 examples listed in question, then see additional link above-

Answer (score 3):

By reading your linked FAA Order and finding references for responsible offices and a little follow-on search, I found this link to the [Office of Mission Support](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/mission_support/) within the Air Traffic Organization.

Airspace analysis appears to be within their purview:

> Mission Support Services oversees the Air Traffic Organization’s
>   activities in:
>
> - Aeronautical Information Manual (PDF)
> - Aeronautical Information Services
> - Air Traffic Organization Environmental Reviews
> - Air Traffic Procedures Advisory Committee (ATPAC)
> - Instrument flight procedures production/charting
> - Metroplex
> - New York/New Jersey/Philadelphia Airspace Redesign
> - Obstruction Evaluation/Airport Airspace Analysis (OE/AAA)
> - Performance-Based Navigation (PBN) Implementation And Usage Dashboard
> - Pilot Web

They provide the following contact information:

> **Address**
>   FAA National Headquarters
>   1028 - 10A
>   800 Independence Ave., SW
>   Washington, DC  20591
>
> Phone: (202) 267-8261

Answer (score 1):

[You can try the local FSDO](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/) as that is generally a decent place to start but the FAA is under no obligation to tell you *why* they do things the way they do.

You may also want to ask around at your local airfield. One of the guys that worked on the KPHL Bravo flys out of the little field I trained on. I met him one evening at an EAA meet up and he told me all kinds of stories about why they made the airspace the way they did. He was not/is not an FAA employee and was on some kind of committee that was put together to design it. You may have luck finding people who had input on the airspace just by asking around.

Comment: Probably best for Law.SE, but why is the FAA under no obligation, couldn't the [freedom of information act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_Information_Act_(United_States)) be used?